# How do i know if .net desctop development is installed already

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, microsoft-file-explorer

I had visual studio 2019 for the longest time but now I want to get into Terraria coding which needs Visual Studio 202, but I'm not sure if it left over some files because when I check my control panel there's a Microsoft XNA framework which I'm pretty sure was part of visual studio code BUT EVEN IF IT ISNT I want to know if I can download visual studio 2022 without the .NET desktop development because I might have it, and or where I can see if I already have it installed like where the file path is and such.

Comment: You're saying Visual Studio Code, but that is a different IDE.  I assume you only mean Visual Studio.  I believe desktop development can be added after you install Visual Studio by using the installer.

Comment: @TimothyG. right it can be installed afterward, what im wondering is if i have it already intalled on my computer.

Comment: Open the installer and see if it is installed already then? Native Windows shouldn't have any kind of development features like this already installed.